# when something is happening "on somebody": does it mean it is happening TO sb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

In Twin Peaks TV series, a room servant in a hotel carrying a glass of milk on a tray says "the milk will get cold on you" to a person unable to get up from the floor, obviously meaning "your milk will get cold".

In a random conversation, I heard the expression "he got drunk on us", in what I think was an affectionate tone.

I am not familiar with this use of "on someone" with verbs/actions. I suspect it is used to describe how an event relates to someone who will experience it - in the 1st example, the servant meaning "you will experience having cold milk (if you dont drink it soon)"; and in the 2nd example, "he got drunk in our company - we experienced him getting drunk".
Am I correct? Or is there a better definition? Or some feel to the phrase? I would like to be able to use it actively... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sense of *on* means that the object of the preposition will experience the condition just specified as something negative, and that the object has a particular connection of focus for the negativity, such as ownership or responsibility.

[Merriam-Webster *on*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)
9 c — used as a function word to indicate the object with respect to some misfortune or disadvantageous event
*the crops died on them*

As you can see at the dictionary link, the word *on* has many very particular senses as a preposition.

Answer (score -1):

You might refer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162636/what-does-it-s-all-on-you-mean

'On *someone*' generally means that '*someone*' is responsible for that.

For example the expression 'this one's on the house', in a bar, restaurant or pub, means that the food/drink is free, i.e. the house (the host) is responsible for the cost of the food/drink, and the customer won't be expected to pay for it.

You could consider also the expression 'don't go dying on us', which means 'don't die, we need you/care about you'. See here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/died+on+me

That means 'dying under our care'.

Thus in 'the milk will go cold on you', he's pointing out that it will no longer be warm if he leaves it. This could be seen as an alternative to 'drink your milk while it's still warm'.

In the case of 'he got drunk on us', there could be a dual meaning which would require a bit more context to decipher. For example, if a restaurant offered a buffet '$50 buffet all-you-can-eat, plus free-flow alcohol: get drunk on us', they are saying 'you are only paying for the food, the alcohol is free'. In the case of 'he got drunk on us', I would say that it is more like 'he got drunk while he was under our care/with us', and perhaps there is something unusual or different about that - perhaps nobody else got drunk, or perhaps he doesn't usually get drunk.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that the person is responsible for causing the situation, just that the thing happens in such a way that it directly affects them. The (presumably hot) milk will get cold before the guest drinks it - the rest of the party found themselves in the company of, and probably responsible for looking after, a drunken man.

Comment: I didn't say anything about 'responsible for causing the situation'. I said 'responsible for that'. In the case of food/drink 'on the house', 'that' refers to the obligation to pay. In the case of a 'patient dying on us', then the patient might well have been suffering a terminal illness, but they are 'in the care of the hospital', so 'that' refers to the obligation to provide medical care to patients.

Comment: I don't think discussing the expression _on the house_ is relevant here; it just confuses the issue.